# How to prevent Google from knowing my passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

I noticed that my notebook has synchronized not only my Chrome bookmarks, but also my passwords to sites. This can't be done on demand, because my other computer can be turned off. And this can't be done encrypted, because browsers can't send passwords if encrypted.

The means that Chrome is sending my passwords to Google.

How can I prevent this?

In other words, how can I prevent any uploading of my passwords to Google servers both relying on Chrome's good will and independently.

I.e. I want some blocking software, which blocks password transform to internet.

Comment: Why can't it be done encrypted?  Chrome uses your Google account credentials to encrypt the passwords.  They are sent to Google servers, but they are encrypted.  You can also encrypt with a separate passphrase.

Comment: note that you cannot depend on google's good will, because such good will is forbidden by law. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patriot_act#Title_V:_Removing_obstacles_to_investigating_terrorism http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FISA_Amendments_Act

Comment: @Paul passwords are encrypted, but Google knows the keys, since it can decrypt is on synced browser. So, Google knows all my passwords to all my sites and it does this without any warnings, by default. I think it is no sense to disable the feature aftewards, because all password are already uploaded to Google.

Comment: @FrankThomas sorry didn't understand, I am bad with legal mambo-yambo language. Can you explain?

Comment: this may get a little off topic, but my point is that entities in a number of countries have the legal authority to demand any information that a company possess about you. my point was simply that no matter how well intentioned a company is it can no longer secure anything you give it, so your best bet in protecting yourself is to give it nothing, even if that means you have less integration across products and services. Trust No One.

Comment: @Dims why do you think that "Google knows the keys"?

Comment: @gronostaj, I think the confusion is due to the fact that Chrome can  synch your passwords automatically, downloading them from your online Google account, decrypting them, and inserting them into web pages without the user ever having enter a password anywhere. The problem is that the OP is forgetting that they *did* enter a password (their Google account password) when they set up Chrome sync. Or maybe they did remember that and want to prevent Chrome from storing their Google account password (which would disable syncing altogether).

Comment: @Dims Google does not need to know the keys for your browser to decrypt the passwords, only your browser needs to know.  Seeing as you signed in to the browser to enable sync in the first place, you provided the key to decrypt.

Comment: @Dims as originally expressed, your question was answerable, now it isn't. Consider rolling back or asking another question about what you want to do.

Answer (score 8):

1: Click the [image](Chrome menu) on the browser toolbar.

2: Select Signed in as `your email address` (**you must be signed in to Chrome already**).
In the "**Sign in**" section, **click Advanced sync settings**.

3: Choose an encryption option:

4: Encrypt synced passwords with your Google credentials: This is the default option. Your saved passwords are encrypted on Google's servers and protected with your Google Account credentials.

5: Encrypt all synced data with your own **sync passphrase**: Select this if you'd like to encrypt all the data you've chosen to sync. You can provide your own **passphrase** that will only be stored on your computer.

Click OK.

**Note**: If you forget your passphrase, you’ll need to reset sync via the Google Dashboard. This will delete all synced data from Google’s servers and disconnect all synced computers and devices, but not the data that’s on your computers or devices. So your current preferences, bookmarks, and passwords will remain available in the browser. You can then re-enable sync with a new passphrase.

For more information see this [support section](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?hl=en).

Comment: I can confirm that with "use your Google Username and Password" a Gsuite admin can access your passwords, even without your password... which is VERY misleading. So set your own sync passphrase, even if it's the same as your google password, as long as no one other than you knows it. Passwords are hashed so that not even Google actually knows it the plain text version.

Answer (score 6):

Just access the "Advanced Sync Settings" in the Settings page, or just type about:settings.

Select *"Choose what to sync"*, disable all the elements that you don't want google to know about.

[image]

Done.

Source:

- https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1281195?hl=en

> The question about "password firewall" software is still opened. I want neither application be able to send my passwords anywhere without explicit permission.

This depends greatly in how the applications are made. The question only gives Google Chrome as reference, and there are enough methods here.

Comment: Sorry, where is this page? What is Chromebook this link is about? I am interested in Google Chrome Web Browser.

Comment: @Dims through the link is about a "chromebook" the same applies to any version of Chrome/ium. I've added screenshots to help and a shortcut.

Answer (score 3):

> I noticed that my notebook has synchronized not only my Chrome bookmarks, but also my passwords to sites. … How can I prevent this?

Just turn off the `Password` setting in the Sync configuration page (`chrome://settings/syncSetup`):

[image: Screenshot of Chrome Synch page with passwords entry turned off]

> I.e. I want some blocking software, which blocks password transform to internet.

What you want is a firewall that can do [deep-packet inspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection). I doubt there’s anything that can detect this specifically, but any firewall that can do DPI can be configured to detect whatever you want, including passwords. The specific steps to do that would depend on the program you end up choosing. Either way, if the password is encrypted, then even a firewall would be unable to detect if it is a password that is being transmitted.

Comment: Moreover: most probably Chrome communicating with it's server via HTTPS, so encryption is very strong and DPI can't help. What I need is something like antivirus software, which intercepts traffic on OS level and checks presence of passwords there.

Comment: > What I need is something like antivirus software, which intercepts traffic on OS level and checks presence of passwords there.   @Dims, that statement is (almost) meaningless. What you are asking would require a program that hacks the OS to observe the memory of other programs and search for strings that you specify (which would mean giving a list of all your passwords—unencrypted—to the program!) I can’t imagine that such a program would exist. Have you tried simply turning the password syncing function off? ಠ_ఠ It’s so much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: @Dims, just in case you are misunderstanding, un-checking the *Passwords* field in the Sync dialog only disables password *syncing* (sending to Google), it does not disable password *saving* which is a [completely different setting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dqdLs.png).

Comment: @hit-and-run-down-voter, what’s the problem? This perfectly answers the question that was asked. Either explain what the problem is, or stow your sour grapes (which is likely the case since you did not down-vote any other answers, even ones that didn’t actually solve the problem). ◔_◔

Comment: Downvoter you should shame for this, this is the answer which resolve the issue from root. However my answer cover some part with encryption but not the all after update of OP until he didn't updated my answer was sufficient enough though.

Comment: @avirk, thanks for the support. Unfortunately anonymous votes will always allow this sort of thing.